# Autoloading a whole namespace in php (for functions instead of a class)

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to autoload a namespace with a bunch of helper functions:

```
<?php

namespace App\Str {
    function contains($haystack, $needles)
    {
        foreach ((array)$needles as $needle) {
            if ($needle !== '' && mb_strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function starts_with($haystack, $needles)
    {
        foreach ((array) $needles as $needle) {
            if ($needle !== '' && substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === (string) $needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Psr-4 composer autoloading doesn't help here:

```
Call to undefined function App\Str\starts_with()
```

I understand know that I can't (lazily) autoload functions, and I'm giving the advice to make a class with static functions, but as I prefer functional programming, I want to first investigate other options. For example, could I somehow (lazily) autoload the whole namespace itself? I want to use this namespace in the following way:

```
use App\Str as Str;

$test = Str\starts_with('test', 't');
```

I want to somehow specify to composer, that if it sees the `App\Str` namespace, it should lazily require the file `app/Str.php`, not really sure how composer works, but wouldn't something like that be possible?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with Classes and prefer functional programming, why not use a Class just as a wrapper and put all your functions as *static* functions inside that wrapper. If you do so you will not be needing to instantiate new objects of that class to use it's functions. You can just do `ClassName::myFunction()` that's because functional code will be hard to maintain later as your code grows.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's not possible. If you want non-lazy autoloading you have to add this to your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Str.php",
        "app/Arr.php"
    ]
}
```

Where each entry is a file name with your functions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled with the same problem, namely:

- I want to use functional programming in PHP
- I don't want to use class wrappers for my functions (static or otherwise)
- I want to load the function definition files only when I am going to use them

The solution that works for me is creating a Loader class for the functional module that loads all the function definition files.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Loader
{
    public function load()
    {
        require_once(__DIR__."/Str.php");
        require_once(__DIR__."/Submodule/File2.php");
        require_once(__DIR__."/Arr.php");
        // etc ...
    }

}
```

Then, when I want to use my functional module, I load it first:

```
<?php

use App;

(new App\Loader())->load();

App\Str\starts_with('test', 't');
```